# Can a brokered CD still count as "Massachusetts Bank Interest" for income tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, brokerage, certificate-of-deposit, massachusetts

On the Massachusetts income tax Form 1, line 5 is for "Interest from Massachusetts Banks". This interest income gets an amount deducted from it ($200 for married filing jointly), and is reported there on the main tax form. Whereas interest from any other sources gets reported separately over on Form 1 Schedule B.

So certainly if I have a savings account with my brick & mortar bank down the street, and get interest from it, the interest from it would be this "Interest from Massachusetts Banks" and get this deduction. But what about if I use a brokerage account (like Fidelity), and purchase a *brokered* CD that is from a Massachusetts bank? There's a sense in which it's Fidelity paying me the interest (in that they're the ones who would be sending me the 1099-INT), and Fidelity isn't a Massachusetts Bank, but there's also a sense in which they are just passing along what is truly just interest that is being paid me via a Massachusetts Bank.

**So for this interest from a brokered CD that's ultimately from a Massachusetts Bank, do I report it on Form 1 Line 5a or does it only show up on Form 1 Schedule B?**

The Form 1 instructions don't really clarify beyond saying that Line 5 is for interest from deposit accounts (like CDs) "in Massachusetts banks", and doesn't clarify whether getting them indirectly through a brokerage counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I decided that I might just try calling up the state and seeing what they said. The person I talked to at the Massachusetts Department of Revenue was quite helpful and said that as long as the amount from the brokerage came on a normal 1099-INT, and it was due to being from a Massachusetts bank, that that portion of the income does indeed count as "Massachusetts bank interest" and goes on the main Form 1. This is true even if the 1099-INT covers both interest from the banks as well as other investment interest, that one would put the portion due to Massachusetts banks on the main Form 1 and the rest of it on the Schedule B.

Comment: I am in MA as well, this is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

From page 10 of the [Form 1 instructions](https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2019/01/16/dor-2018-inc-form-1-inst.pdf):

---

#### Line 5. Interest from Massachusetts Banks

*Enter  in  line  5a  the  total  amount  of  interest  received or credited to deposit accounts (term and time  deposits,  **including  certificates  of  deposit**, savings accounts, savings shares, and NOW accounts) in Massachusetts banks. Then, enter your exemption  amount  in  line  5b  (if  married  filing

jointly, enter $200; otherwise, enter $100). Subtract line 5b from 5a and enter the result in line 5, but not less than 0.*

---

I'd also check with [this resource](https://mataxaide.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/2019-mass-manual-fall-final2.pdf) from MA Tax Aide. Appendix B starts:

[image]

Since a "Massachusetts bank" requires that the bank in question has a physical presence in the Commonwealth. So long as the CD is with a bank with a brick-and-mortar shop in MA, that should suffice. My guess is that most brokerages themselves do *not* have a physical presence in MA, but the bank that holds the CD may.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if your last paragraph is saying that a non-Massachusetts brokerage holding a CD issued by a Massachusetts bank counts, or not. And I'm also not sure how you're getting that conclusion based on the document you've shown. But I appreciate the information!